# Select Material UI, wrong position when i have one item on my list. REACTJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i have that select and menuItem from @material-ui/core. When I only have one item in my list, the position of that item is wrong. How can I raise the position of this item?

[image]

```
<Select
  MenuProps={{
    anchorOrigin: {
      vertical: "bottom",
      horizontal: "left",
    },
    transformOrigin: {
      vertical: "top",
      horizontal: "left",
    },
    getContentAnchorEl: null,
  }}
  value={value}
  onChange={chavearAccordionsSetarParametro}
  labelId="remedio-label"
  id="remedio"
  name="remedio"
  className={classes.containerSelect}
>
  {list.map((element) => (
    <MenuItem
      value={element.Description}
      key={element.RemedyId}
      className={classes.MenuItem}
    >
      {element.Description}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>;
```

Comment: Can you post the styles for the class names - containerSelect and MenuItem?

Comment: sure. MenuItem dont have any props in your class. And containerSelect have position: 'relative' and width: '100%',

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox so I can reproduce?